# mysqld_safe Disabled Internet Connection

Tags: mysql, unix

I was trying to get mysql running on my machine and ran sudo `mysqld_safe` from my home directory. This, I have found, was not a wise decision. Anyone have any idea what it might have changed to make reaching the internet impossible? My wireless card works fine and connects to the router, but I cannot resolve any external host (localhost works fine.)

Running the command killed my terminal and prevented any other instance of a terminal from launching before a reboot. I can't find anything else wrong with the system besides the inability to resolve remote hosts.

Bootable Backups save the day again.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a mySQL expert, but it sounds like you just fluked into another issue when running mysqld_safe.   Mysqld_safe will not touch your routing tables or change your DNS settings.

I'd look elsewhere for the problem.

Comment: Any advice on how I could repair my routing table or DNS?

Comment: Sounds like your backup did the job.   Personally, I would run a test and see if mysqld_safe breaks it again.  It shouldn't but if it does put the info up here stating that a test proved that launching mysqld_safe caused the problem.  Run lsof to see if any files are affected by mysqld_safe.